# Read user field via Javascript/REST: Some users are NULL

Tags: list, rest, user, json

I have a simple list with a simple user field. I can assign users, save the item and everything was working fine...
...until I tried to access the list via REST call within a Javascript.

Some of the users are simply not appearing in the resuling JSON/XML... The value of that field is NULL. The problem appears not for all users, but just for some

- All users come from an Active Directory
- Displayed users and "null"-users have both the same permissions in AD
- the list view, the edit form and the display form are displaying everything as they should. It's just the result of the REST call
- The user who actually executes the script has Admin permissions

I have no idea what's going on. Even if the users within the list wouldn't have no permissions at all, I think they should appear in the list anyway - don't they?

```
csOperationsForm.ReplaceMaDropDown = function() {
    var apiCallUrl = '/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'Member Associations\')/items?$select=ID,Country,DevelopmentManager/UserName,DevelopmentOfficer/UserName&$orderby=Country&$expand=DevelopmentManager/UserName,DevelopmentOfficer/UserName&$top=1000';
    $.ajax({
        url: apiCallUrl,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
        },
        success: function(jsonData){
            if(jsonData.d.results[0] != null){                          
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.d.results.length; i++) {
                    var dm = jsonData.d.results[i].DevelopmentManager.UserName;
                    var do = jsonData.d.results[i].DevelopmentOfficer.UserName;
                }
            }           
        },
        error: function(data){console.log("An error occured..." + data.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: add as much of your code as you are allowed so we can can copy/paste

Comment: thx... I added some parts of the code...